# Need help unpacking the interdependence of axiomatic set theory and first-order logic

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

I'm currently self-studying both Von Neumann Set Theory (not ZFC but rather axiomatic set theory with the undefined notion of ***class***) and First-Order Logic.

I've been self-studying the following textbooks for each respectively.

- A Book of Set Theory by Charles C Pinter
- Mathematical Logic by Chiswell

Unfortunately, both implicitly assume a consistent formation of the other leading to potentially circular definitions.

I would like to understand each field of math so that no circular definitions exist.

For example,

The definition of First-Order Signature $\sigma$ relies upon the definition of Set and consequently Class among other things (which I'll ignore for the sake of argument).

[image]

[image]

But at this point, one cannot assume there exists a single Class and consequently a single Set. Thus, we cannot assert the existence of even a single variable or constant symbol.

For that, we need an Axiom from Set Theory. For example, the Axiom of Empty Set, which asserts the existence of an "empty set" put precisely as

$$\exists x \forall Y(Y \notin x)$$

However, this assumes we can use variables $x, Y$ in first-order logic but per my previous point, we cannot assert the existence of even a single variable.

Can you please help me unpack this and potentially other circular definitions? Additional resource recommendations are welcome.

Comment: First order logic is only a slight abstraction of things you can write on paper. It should be comprehended prior to the axioms of set theory.

Comment: Versions of this question have been asked many times on MO and math.SE. Follow the links in the comments at https://mathoverflow.net/q/448507/1946.

Comment: If logicians and set theorists are not allowed to use logic and sets, why are number theorists allowed to use numbers? It is not the job of foundations of mathematics to "build foundations" from nothing, but rather to reflect on how mathematics operates and what its overall structure and methods are, *using mathematics itself*. This is not circular, at least not any more than talking about English in English.

Comment: You would probably enjoy Monk’s [book](https://euclid.colorado.edu/~monkd/monk11.pdf) on $MK$ class theory; in particular, it has a short introduction intuitively describing the logic used in the development of set theory throughout the book, and has a 12 page appendix developing everything fully formally (although I haven’t ever really gone through that appendix; at a certain point I just trust that it all works out.)